# grep match with string1 OR string2

Tags: grep, solaris

I want to grep 2 patterns in a file on ***Solaris UNIX***.

That is grep 'pattern1 **OR** pattern2' filename.

The following command does NOT work:

`grep 'pattern1\|pattern2' filename`

What is wrong with this command?

**NOTE:** I am on Solaris

Answer (score 22):

What operating system are you on?

It will work with on systems with GNU grep, but on BSD, Solaris, etc., `\|` is not supported.

Try `egrep` or `grep -E`, e.g.

```
egrep 'pattern1|pattern2'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want POSIX functionality (i.e. Linux-like behavior) you can put the POSIX 2-compatible binaries at the beginning of your path:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/xpg4/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:[...]
```

There is also /usr/xpg6 which is POSIX 1 compatible.

```
/usr/bin: SVID/XPG3
/usr/xpg4/bin: POSIX.2/POSIX.2a/SUS/SUSv2/XPG4
/usr/xpg6/bin: POSIX.1-2001/SUSv3
```

Answer (score 0):

That command works fine for me. Please add additional information such as your platform and the exact regular expression and file contents you're using (minimized to the smallest example that still reproduces the issue). (I would add a comment to your post but don't have enough reputation.)

Comment: pattern is simply a word and I work on an unix solaris machine.

Answer (score 0):

That should be correct. Make sure that you do or don't add the appropriate spaces i.e. "pattern1\|pattern2" vs "pattern1\| pattern2".

Are you sure you aren't just having problems with cases or something? try the -i switch.

Answer (score 0):

That depends entirely on what pattern1 and pattern2 are.  If they're just words, it should work, otherwise you'll need:

```
grep '\(pattern1\)\|\(pattern2\)'
```

Comment: the patterns are just words and it says unknown escape sequence '\|'

Answer (score 0):

An arcane method using `fgrep` (ie: fixed strings) that works on Solaris 10...

Provide a pattern-list, with each pattern separated by a NEWLINE, yet quoted so as to be interpreted by the shell as one word:-

```
fgrep 'pattern1
pattern2' filename
```

This method also works for `grep`, `fgrep` and `egrep` in `/usr/xpg4/bin`, although the pipe-delimited ERE in any `egrep` is sometimes the least fussy.

You can insert arbitrary newlines in a string if your shell allows history-editing, eg: in `bash` issue `C-v C-j` in either emacs mode or vi-command mode.

Answer (score 0):

`egrep -e "string1|string2"` works for me in SunOS 5.9 (Solaris)