# grep OR command not working unix solaris

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep, solaris

I able to do single grep but can not do OR search in unix solaris

Please see below examples i tried...

```
-bash-3.00$ echo "Hello hi" | grep -i "Hello"
Hello hi
-bash-3.00$ echo "Hello hi" | grep -i "Hello\|hi"
-bash-3.00$
```

Comment: Does it work to you `egrep -i "Hello|hi"`? (in case it does not, I won't post an answer).

Comment: it will select both I guess . `echo "Hello hi" | grep -i "Hello\|hi"` should work

Comment: use `perl -lne 'print if(/Hello|hi/)'`

Comment: @fedorqui : yes, its working

Comment: @fedorqui `-E` is specified by `POSIX` so it should work with all sane `grep` implementations.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth, yes they are equal per definition as seen in `man grep`.

Comment: @logan are you sure `echo "Hello hi" | grep -i "Hello\|hi"` doesn't return anything ?

Comment: @fedorqui That's what I meant...it has to work, if it didn't there would be something seriously wrong with OP's system.

Comment: here it is : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5918260/2542215

Comment: @aelor : yes its not returning anything. thats why posted a question here

Comment: Aaah @AdrianFrühwirth see what [Charles Duffy commented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22559902/grep-or-command-not-working-unix-solaris/22559988?noredirect=1#comment34336889_22559988), `\|` is a GNU extension, so it won't work in Solaris.

Comment: @fedorqui Yep, didn't know about that extension but that certainly explains why it didn'tw ork for OP :-) I was only talking about `grep -E` which must also work on Solaris.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of `egrep`, which per definition is the same as `grep -E`. It interprets the patterns as extended regular expressions, so that `grep -E "hello|hi"` means: "grep either `hello` or `hi`".

So both of these should work:

```
echo "Hello hi" | egrep -i "hello|hi"  # as you are using -i, no need to low/upper case

echo "Hello hi" | grep -Ei "hello|hi"
```

In case of doubt, you can always check your `man grep` and see what they explain there. As I do not have access to any Solaris server, I cannot test myself.

Comment: i am still confused as to why `echo "Hello hi" | grep -i "Hello\|hi"` is not working ?

Comment: @aelor, `\|` is a GNU extension, not part of standard POSIX.2 BRE.

Comment: what is the difference between grep & egrep and why is not working in grep ?

Comment: @logan grep -E and egrep are same and as I mentioned , `\|` will work  on systems with GNU grep, but on BSD, Solaris, etc., `\|` is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `awk` for this:

```
echo "Hello hi" | awk '/Hello|Hi/'
Hello hi
```