# regex failed to match using {M,N} on SunOS

Tags: regex, grep, sunos

I have the following sample file and regular expression.

testing.txt

```
testing                  aa
a bc de
e                        aa
ba                        Z
testing                  bb
testing                  ac
```

my regular expression using egrep

```
egrep '[ ]{2,}' testing.txt
```

The above regular expression attempts to find contiguous white spaces in a line.
However, the result returned is empty.

the regulartion expression below works for 1 or more spaces. However that is not what I want.

```
egrep '[ ]+' testing.txt
```

Comment: Which version of egrep are you using? `egrep --version`

Comment: Are there spaces at all? Try adding a tab to the bracket expression.

Comment: egrep --version gives me invalid syntax.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, nope that didnt work either(I suppose you mean adding \t into the [ ] brackets)

Comment: No, you can't add escape sequences in a bracket expression. A literal tab symbol.

Comment: @l'L'l, ok let me try that out. because on the system i can see that the OS is 10 years old ... SunOS 2006 ... jesus

Comment: @l'L'l, ok it doesn't work either

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, i have tried both [ ]\t and [ \t].

Comment: @Mox: Maybe try `[ ][ ]+` or `\s\s+`

Comment: A backslash inside a bracket expression is treated as a literal backslash. A `[\t]` matches a ``\`` or`t`. Use a literal tab inside the *bracket expression*, it is no character class. Another thing is  that in BRE regex you need to escape the braces `\{n,m\}`, you do not need that Iin ERE. No idea what exact flavor egrep supports.

Comment: @l'L'l, wow that actually worked. so am i safe to assume that this OS doesnt suppose {M, N} syntax for regex? =/

Comment: @Mox: Yeah, I think that `{n,n}` repetitions for character classes came later on in the egrep world ( or at least after the time of the version you're using ).

Comment: @ILl Limiting quantifier comes with BRE, it is rather old.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Indeed — which is even more perplexing that the OP's version doesn't seem to have it.

Comment: I invariably end up using Perl on Sun systems - it is FAR more consistent.

Comment: `\s` is almost certain not to work; these escapes were introduced in Perl, and were unknown in `grep` variants at the time.

Comment: I wonder if `grep '[ ]\{2,\}' testing.txt` works at all. I found some stange help: [*Traditional egrep did not support the `{`  metacharacter, and some  egrep  implementations support `\{` instead, so portable scripts should avoid `{` in egrep patterns and should use `[{]` to match a literal `{.*`*](http://www.manpages.info/sunos/grep.1.html).

Comment: I think this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918150/solaris-grep-with-or-functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your system is old, [this help reference](http://www.manpages.info/sunos/grep.1.html) might be describing the issue:

> **Traditional egrep did not support the `{`  metacharacter**,  and some  egrep  implementations support `\{` instead, so portable scripts should avoid `{` in egrep patterns and should use `[{]` to match a literal `{`.

That means, that - if `grep '[ ]\{2,\}' testing.txt` does not work - you are better off using Perl or GNU grep to achieve what you want.

Also, `egrep '[ ][ ]+' testing.txt` seems to be a workaround only in the current situation, and will not scale, but it certainly will help you for the time being.

Comment: ya unfortunately, it is the company's server haha so i have no power to upgrade ...