# Whats wrong with below regex

Tags: regex, unix

What is wrong with below regex in unix ?

```
echo AB345678  | sed -n '/^\([a-zA-Z]\{2\}[0-9]\{6\}|[0-9]\{8\}\)$/p'
echo 12345678  | sed -n '/^\([a-zA-Z]\{2\}[0-9]\{6\}|[0-9]\{8\}\)$/p'
```

i am not getting the output :(

I mean the string I echoed why is it not matching with my regex?
Whats wrong with my regex?

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it. It is exactly the one you wrote. It is quite happy, probably.

Answer (score 2):

The alternation operator in the BRE regex syntax must be defined as an escaped pipe `\|` (similar to `(` and `)`):

```
echo "AB345678"  | sed -n '/^\([a-zA-Z]\{2\}[0-9]\{6\}\|[0-9]\{8\}\)$/p'
                                                      ^^
```

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/yJu0lR).

Comment: I tried both of the below , but still no output.
    echo AB345678  | sed -n '/^\([a-zA-Z]\{2\}[0-9]\{6\}\|[0-9]\{8\}\)$/p'
    echo "AB345678" | sed -n '/^\([a-zA-Z]\{2\}[0-9]\{6\}\|[0-9]\{8\}\)$/p'

Comment: Does it mean you are on Sun OS? See [this thread](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151020).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That looks like a red herring to me.  The XPG4 `sed` does have a slightly different feature set, but as per the documentation I was able to google, your fix should work, unless there is something the OP is not telling us.  (I suppose there are multiple versions of XPG4 `sed` as well; perhaps the OP should [edit] their question to indicate the OS version etc.)

Comment: Quoting these strings should not matter in any reasonable shell.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew   : Yes , I am on SUN OS.
I tried all the combinations posted in this forum , but still not able to get output..

Comment: Try `egrep '^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]|[0-9][0-9])[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$'` - I am afraid the regex is implemented very poorly in Sun OS. From what I know, the [bound quantifiers do not work well there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38822261/regex-failed-to-match-using-m-n-on-sunos).

Comment: I've tried some combinations on Sun OS 5.8. It seems it's the pipe operator that doesn't work, escaped or not. Using the first part alone, everything is fine

Comment: This pattern won't work without a pipe as the alternation operator. The only way out then is to install the GNU sed. Sorry, I cannot help with that.

Answer (score 0):

In a more complicated expression you can add **'-r'** to sed options instead of escaping sensitive characters.

From sed manual:

> -r, --regexp-extended
>         use extended regular expressions in the script.

Answer:

```
echo AB345678 | sed -nr '/^([a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}|[0-9]{8})$/p'
                      ^
echo 12345678 | sed -nr '/^([a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}|[0-9]{8})$/p'
                      ^
```

Comment: @LalitSomnathe Why do not you look at my answer. I think is more elegant.
This question should also be tagged #sed, so that this problem does not apply to the regex or unix systems, but the syntax of sed.