# Searching for files, within a working directory (and subdirectories in it) containing strings on the same line

Tags: linux, text, grep, directory, find

Normally I use `grep -r "text" .` for searching for a file within my working directory (including all subdirectories in it) that would contain a string.

Now I want to find which file or files (within my working directory, and all subdirectories in it) would contain two or more strings in a same line. How to achieve that?

I've searched for posts already, but they are most related to find two or more strings in a line on a given file, but not on a whole working directory (including the subdirectories in it).

As already explained and highlighted, this question is not a duplicateo

Comment: Probly `awk` can help: `awk '/text1/ && /text2/' file`

Comment: `grep -IR -E '<string one>|<string two>'`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grep match with string1 OR string2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5918150/608639). [grepping using the “|” alternative operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6775904/608639), etc.

Comment: I do not think they are duplicates; they are focused on files; and I'm focusing on a whole directory including the subdirectories in it;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was very easy to solve:

```
grep -r "first_text" * | grep "second_text"
```

In that way i got the file that I was looking for, which had `first_text` and `second_text` on the same line. When trying it with many other combinations of texts, I found also the files containing the texts IN THE SAME LINE.